# Installing Paypal Django SDK on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, paypal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to install the paypal sdk for my django app hosted on elasticbeanstalk.
I tried putting this in my requirements.txt :

```
awsebcli==3.6.2
boto==2.38.0
botocore==1.3.13
Django==1.9
django-localflavor==1.1
django-storages==1.1.8
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
djangotoolbox==1.8.0
Pillow==2.9.0
paypalrestsdk==1.11.0
psycopg2==2.6
virtualenv==12.0.7
```

Paypal sdk says it requires libssl-dev libffi-dev libraries but when I put them in my config file uinstalling via yum it said they were not found.  Here is my config file for reference (I tried libssl-dev and libssl-devel both did not work)

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    openssl-devel: []
    libssl-dev: []
    libffi-dev: []
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
      option_name: WSGIPath
      value: HERA/wsgi.py
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
      value: HERA.settings
    - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
      value: SECRET_KEY
    - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      value: ACCESS_KEY
```

has anyone had any success installing the paypal SDK for their elastic beanstalk server?

Comment: Can you look at `/var/log/eb-activity.log`? Can you ssh to the instance and try installing the dependencies manually first using `yum install`? Once you get it working using yum install you can put the correct configuration in ebextensions.

Comment: Thanks.  Ssh'ing into the instance and manually installing OPENssl and libffi-dev did the trick!

Comment: But I would definitely recommend using the ebextensions to do the same. EC2 instances can be replaced when they are part of an autoscaling group depending on your configuration. The new replacements may not have the libffi-dev package and your service may not start. I would recommend looking at `/var/log/eb-activity.log` so you can figure out why the ebextension failed in the first place.